How to indefinitely restart a systemd service until it succedes?
I have a systemd service on a machine that could be killed (or otherwise fail) which I want to restart upon failure indefinitely, trying a restart every 2 seconds until it succeeds (or the end of the world happens)
I am completely lost in the zillions of timer entries available for a service but after gathering information here and there I finally came to
[Unit]
Description=ssh tunnel to srv
After=network.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=2s
Type=simple
ExecStart=ssh -N -R 58384:127.0.0.1:8384 XXX.com -p 2223 -i /root/.ssh/srv.private.openssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60
Environment=

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

It works, but when doing a systemctl start the_name_of_the_service the prompt hangs for an extended amount of time and finally succeeds.
This is not a timeout of sorts, I strongly suspect that my configuration makes the service wait some time (probably a combination of ServerAliveInterval and RestartSec) and when systems confirms that the service is live, it gives its OK (= the startup is done). Thsi si speculation, though.
I am surprised to not have found instructions for a seemingly typical case: a service that can fail needs to be restarted every X seconds until it eventually succedes (or not, but the process runs indefinitely). How can I do that?

It's probably because of the dependencies (i.e., it waits at least until the system is "online" / the wait online service timed out).

@TomYan that would be surprising because it is a live server (i.e. I am connected via ssh when doing the systemctl start. I am not sure how networkd-wait-online.service is supposed to behave, though

Well, you can try to check its status before and after systemctl start your_service. Probably it is waiting for some interface that it doesn't need to wait (because you haven't leveraged RequiredForOnline=no as per your need).

@TomYan you are correct. I removed the lines related to systemd-networkd-wait-online and I cannot reproduce the problem (it is still present on other services that still have the lines). Would that mean that the solution is RestartSec=2s (= attempt to restart every 2 seconds) and StartLimitIntervalSec=0 (= there is no limit on the number of attempts)? ← I still vaguely understand these two entries, thus my question. If so would you be so kind as to turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?
